# Installing Anaconda On Linux If Miniconda already installed

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda, centos7, singularity-container

I am using a CentOs Distribution of Linux and have miniconda already installed along with conda environments that I created with it.  I am trying to install anaconda now.  Do I have to uninstall miniconda first?  I have some environments that I created with miniconda that I would like to keep.  Is it possible to keep those environments if I uninstall it?  The reason I need anaconda is I'd like to create environments inside my singularity container.  How would it be possible to keep both? Thanks.

Comment: _The reason I need anaconda is I'd like to create environments inside my singularity container._ Is that not possible using Miniconda?

Answer (score 0):

Both Miniconda and Anaconda include Conda, so no need to install both. Given either, a new environment with all the Anaconda distribution packages can be created using

```
conda create --name my_anaconda_env anaconda
```

Note that Python versions can be specified as part of this, e.g.,

```
conda create --name my_anaconda37_env anaconda python=3.7
```